# Determine $P(X=k)$ if given a generating function

Tags: probability

Simple question: If I have a non-negative, integer valued, random variable $X$ that has a generating function $g_x(t)=log(\frac{1}{1-qt})$ how would I go about determining $P(X=k)$ for {k = 0, 1, 2, ...n} ?

Comment: The generating function $g_x(t) = \sum_{n \ge 0} g_n t^n$ is the generating function of the $g_n$, what are those values?

Comment: I am still confused about $Fx(x)$ in the title of the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $F_X(x)=P(X=x)$

Comment: @vonbrand From your equation $g_n$ would be $P(X=k)$ correct? How would I solve for that?

Comment: Ah, probably best to stick with one notation or the other, @user61147. $P(X=k)$ is clearer, and it isn't quite as confusing since there are two very different $X$s in $F_{X}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that $$ g_x(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^kP(X=k)$$ and provided the hint above, it can be found that $$ P(X=k)= \frac{q^k}{k}$$ where $q$ can be found by knowing that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k)= 1$$  Therefore: $$P(X=k) = \frac{(1-e^{-1})^k}{k}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: In general, $$\\log \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}$$

when $|z|<1$.

Comment: I'm confused then, since $g_x(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^kP(X=k)$ Would that mean $P(X=k)=\frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: No, you don't have $g_x(t)=\log\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)$, do you?

Comment: Could you please show me how to work this?

Comment: Please show some effort, first. @user61147

Comment: :) I am. I am tried to get the $log(\frac{1}{1-t})$ from $log(\frac{1}{1-qt})$ but I don't know how to do that. So now I am trying to get the first and second derivative of $g_x(t)$ which is also proving quite the task, am I on the right track at least? I'm really new to probability and don't really know the first step.

Comment: Why do you assume $z=t$? You have a formula for $\log \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$ and you want a formula for $log\left(\frac{1}{1-qt}\right)$. What is $z$?

Comment: if I let $z=qp$, then $\\log \left(\frac{1}{1-qp}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{q^kz^k}{k}$ so my $P(X=k)=\frac{q^k}{k}$ for $k\gt1$...right? what about $0\lt k\lt1$

Comment: What is $p$? You've added something complete new. When you let $z$ equal to anything, how do you get $q^kz^k$ in the right side? $z$ is gone. If you know how to compute $\log \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$ what value do you want to use for $z$ to compute $\log \left(\frac{1}{1-qt}\right)$?

Comment: sorry I meant $\\log \left(\frac{1}{1-qt}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{q^kt^k}{k}$

Comment: What is $p$, though? Why introduce a new variable?

Comment: sorry again, $p$ should be $t$ $z=qt$. I apologize I'm working several problems and all the variables are getting mixed up in my head.